# Elegant way to process and skip first line(s) (containing metadata) when reading an array from file in Python (possibly pandas)?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, import

Suppose I have a file like this `bla.txt`:

```
    21        27       268       288       
55.1   21.2   25.5   23.5   22.3   20.8
28.3   27.1   27.2   26.   25.   23.1 
29.8   28.3   29.0   28.6   27.2   24.4
```

The first line contains metadata which I would like to use later in my script (`a, b, c, d` in my script below), then the rest is a plain array which is easy to read.
Is there a way to process this first line while skipping it at the reading time of the array?

In other words, how to do the following in a more elegant/pythonic way?

```
import numpy as np

fname = 'bla.txt'

with open(fname) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    a, b, c, d = [float(x) for x in lines[0].split()]

myarray = np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=1)
```

**EDIT**:
Solution with `pandas` are welcome. 
[Note that ideally, a solution able to process and skip more than one metadata line would be perfect]

Comment: Probably something like `next(f)` just before the readlines could work.

Comment: Use `f.readline()` if you are only interested in the first line.  Otherwise 2 file reads like this is clean enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are iterators over their lines, so you can just use `next(f)` to get the first line AND move the iterator pointer to the second one. Then (in the `with` block) you can pass the opened file `f` to `numpy.loadtxt()`, so it only starts reading from the second line:

```
import numpy as np

fname = 'bla.txt'

with open(fname) as f:
    first = next(f)
    a, b, c, d = [float(x) for x in first.split()]
    myarray = np.loadtxt(f) # no skiprows here
```

Answer (score 4):

You can tell `numpy.loadtxt` to skip rows.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.loadtxt('bla.txt', skiprows=1)
array([[55.1, 21.2, 25.5, 23.5, 22.3, 20.8],
       [28.3, 27.1, 27.2, 26. , 25. , 23.1],
       [29.8, 28.3, 29. , 28.6, 27.2, 24.4]])
```

You can get the first line of any file without numpy with

```
>>> with open('bla.txt') as f:
...     line1 = next(f)
... 
>>> line1
'    21        27       268       288       \n'
```

If your header line wasn't missing values you could also just read in the whole file with `loadtxt` and then slice the array into a data and a header part.

You did not tag it, but I recommend using `pandas` for convenience in your specific case.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('bla.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
>>> line1 = list(df.columns)
>>> data = df.reset_index().values
>>> 
>>> line1
['21', '27', '268', '288']
>>> data
array([[55.1, 21.2, 25.5, 23.5, 22.3, 20.8],
       [28.3, 27.1, 27.2, 26. , 25. , 23.1],
       [29.8, 28.3, 29. , 28.6, 27.2, 24.4]])
```

Comment: If the first line would fit in terms of number of entries, i.e. would work as a header, you could use `np.genfromtxt`, so that you get named columns and can index the data array by column names.

Comment: Thanks @timgeb. It seems to me that the first part of your answer does not bring new info (`skiprows = 1` within numpy) as this is already how I do it in my question ;-) But thanks for the nice suggestion the use of `pandas`! Yet, this solution seems less general than @bruno desthuilliers's one (which can handle multiple lines of metadata, any number of columns etc).

Answer (score 0):

Just do `lines = f.readlines()[1:]` instead of `lines = f.readlines()`.

Comment: reading the whole file in memory to only get the first line is certainly not the best thing to do.